# How to open video from a video link in an overlay on the same page?

Tags: 7, navigation, modal-dialogs

How to open a video from a video link in an overlay on the same page? For example, If you go to google news you would have seen the video attached on the link, open as an OVERLAY, and play on the same page. My question is related to external video links.

Suppose a user shares a video link in a textarea any where on my website, I want it to open and play in a popup. It can be an input filter which I can enable from one of the text formats.

I have tried [opengraph filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/opengraph_filter), which is generating a thumbnail preview, but I want it to play that video on-site when a user clicks on that thumbnail.

Please do not suggest drupal overlay as it is known to create problems.

Comment: you may be interested by the colorbox module. See the "inline" settings to load it where you want in wysiwyg

Comment: Could you use an *embedded* video - like this one: https://titan.uio.no/node/1138 ?  (This is D7 + Bootstrap, using `iframe class="embed-responsive-item"`)

Comment: I am talking about the text formats (plain text, filtered html and full html). To work I guess I need a filter. I do not want to use bootstrap. There is a module named "custom filter", but i do not know how to use it.